# Est-ce que « Il commande verre sur verre » se dit?

Tags: choix-de-mot, constructions, formulation-idiomatique, formulation

Contexte

Quand nous sortons en boîte, il boit de l’alcool avec excès: il commande verre sur verre.

J’avais en pensée d’écrire plutôt « il commande un verre après l’autre sans répit. » mais elle n’exprime pas l’idée que la personne concernée ingurgite son verre pour en commander un autre l’instant suivant et ainsi de suite.

Il faut savoir que la première proposition en titre a été pensée pour rendre l’idée plus concise et plus fluide à l’oral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La tournure est compréhensible et même assez usitée pour que le modèle soit mentionné dans le TLFi, à l'entrée [**sur**](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/sur) :

> [Marque la répétition rapide, l'enchaînement; type *faire **bêtise sur bêtise***] *On va faire **flambée sur flambée**. Au matin, je veux qu'il y ait ici dedans un tas de cendres, de quoi remplir une brouette* (Bernanos, Mouchette, 1937, p. 1282).
> ♦ ***Coup sur coup***, loc. adv. À la suite. *Sarah s'était amusée à lui faire boire **coup sur coup** six coupes de champagne* (Gide, Faux-monn., 1925, p. 1013).

***Coup sur coup*** s'est émancipé du terme le composant et ne nécessite pas qu'il soit question de coup. Il suffit que tout s'enchaîne très rapidement. Pour ce, cette expression est probablement la plus commune de toutes celles utilisant la structure ***x sur x***. Mais elle n'empêche nullement l'utilisation d'autres termes :

- Il passe ***assistant sur assistant***, personne ne peut travailler longtemps avec lui.
- La route est très mauvaise. Nous subissons ***crevaison sur crevaison*** et évitons les déplacements inutiles.
- Tandis que les ventes de produits d’intérieur  (hifi, électroménager, canapés...) à destination des pays subissant ***confinement sur confinement*** ont explosé, le plus grand producteur de vélos au monde a aussi profité des déconfinements et des envies d'éviter la promiscuité des transports en commun.  <sub>[**Source**](https://www.lci.fr/economie/video-pandemie-de-covid-19-masques-velos-electriques-les-exportations-chinoises-ne-s-etaient-jamais-aussi-bien-portees-2177818.html)</sub>

Et donc aussi, sans problème aucun :

> Il commande ***verre sur verre***.

---

Un dernier exemple, question de s'offrir une pittoresque anecdote tirée de *L'intransigeant* du 6 août 1921, reflet d'une époque où les ordinateurs n'avaient pas encore envahi le quotidien des humains :

[image: description]

Comment: Très bonne réponse, merci Pas un clue.

Comment: @Jean-LouFrenette Mais de rien. Je cherchais justement des exemples avec d'autres mots. Difficile de choisir cependant, il y en a tellement. Au final, j'en ai choisi une qui a ajouté un sourire à ma journée...